# Questions about the chapter "Abstract class field theory" in Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory"

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am trying to learn chapter IV, "Abstract class field theory", from Neukirch's book "Algebraic Number Theory". My problems occur in paragraphs 4 and 5 of that chapter. On two occasions, Neukirch claims that particular field extensions are Galois but I am not able to see why. Maybe someone can help.

In what follows, let $k$ be a field with separable closure $\overline{k}$ and absolute Galois group $G$. All other mentioned fields $K,L$ will be intermediate fields of $\overline{k}/k$, i.e. $k \subseteq K, L \subseteq \overline{k}$. Moreover, assume that a fixed, continuous and surjective homomorphism $d:G \to \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is given. For an intermediate field $K$, denote by $G_K$ the Galois group $\text{Gal}(\overline{k}/K)$.

**Defintions:** For an intermediate field $L$, denote by $I_L$ the kernel of $d$ restricted to $G_L$. The **maximal unramified extension** of $L$ is the fixed field of $I_L$, i.e. the field
$$\{a \in \overline{k}:\sigma a =a \ \ \forall\sigma \in I_L\}.$$
Moreover, an extension $L/K$ of intermediate fields is called **unramified** if $I_K=I_L$.

**My Questions:**

1. Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension and assume $(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}:d(G_K)) < \infty$. Let $\widetilde{L}$ denote the maximal unramified extension of $L$. Neukirch claims that the extension $\widetilde{L}/K$ is also Galois. Why?
2. Let $L/K$ be a unramified finite extension. Neukirch seems to suggest that $L/K$ is Galois since he denotes the automorphism group by $G(L/K)$ - a notation he only uses in the case of Galois extensions and Galois groups. So, does $L/K$ being unramified and finite implies that $L/K$ is Galois? If so, why?

Comment: (1) Useful trick in this context: to show something is Galois, it suffices to show that all elements of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ act on $\Gal(\tilde{L}/K)$. For $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$, you know that $\sigma(\tilde{L})$ is unramified over $\sigma(L) = L$ and therefore is contained in $\tilde{L}$, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: (2) In section 5 of that chapter of Neukich, I think that these are supposed to be local fields. So the Hilbert class field is not relevant (that is only a global construction --- local fields tend to have infinitely many unramified extensions). Instead, you can use the equivalence of categories between finite extensions of the residue field and unramified extensions of the field --- in fact, all finite unramified extensions of a local field are not only Galois but have cyclic Galois group.

Comment: Just another comment: sorry, I learned this stuff from a different book, and I skimmed through Neukirch too quickly. It seems like he isn't assuming that L/K are local fields, but rather that $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ has a surjective homomorphism to $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}$. In this case, it seems like the "maximal unramified extension" according to his definition in this context has Galois group $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}$, which is abelian and hence all subextensions are Galois as promised.